# Startup applications - I want to set a clock on the 2nd display on startup

Tags: autostart, startup-applications

I want to see the clock (tty-clock in this case) on the 2nd display at the start of the system. But I don't know how to set it properly. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to add add a startup scripts so that it will display your tty-clock on your second display at startup.

first you have to find which is your current display, for that simply enter this in your terminal:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

to continue we assume it was `0.1`

then simply create a file like `.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart/`

and put this inside

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tty-clock
Exec=xterm -display :0.1 -geometry 90x30 -e tty-clock
```

then save and restart